# Optimilization outputstream write

Tags: android, stream, outputstream

I have an optimalization question. I have a video file (.mp4) loaded into my android program. This file is 67 megabytes. I want to send this file which is translated to a byte array over a serial connection. The Baud rate is 115200 BAUD. I can receive my message just fine the problem is that it takes over an hours to completely get to the other side. Is there a way to improve my code below?

```
OutputStream out = serverConnection.getOutputStream();
        
        FmiClientConsole.consoleAppendString("video length: " + this.video.length);

        byte[][] byteArrayChunks = createArrayChunk(this.video, 4096);

        int count = 0;
        FmiClientConsole.consoleAppendString("length total: " + byteArrayChunks.length);
        for (byte[] chunk : byteArrayChunks) {
            FmiClientConsole.consoleAppendString("len: " + chunk.length);

            out.write(chunk, 0 , chunk.length);

            FmiClientConsole.consoleAppendString("count: " + count);
            count++;
        }
        out.flush();
```

create array chunk method

```
private static byte[][] createArrayChunk(byte[] array, int chunkSize) {
    int numOfChunks = (int) Math.ceil((double) array.length / chunkSize);
    byte[][] output = new byte[numOfChunks][];

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfChunks; i++) {
        int start = i * chunkSize;
        int length = Math.min(array.length - start, chunkSize);

        byte[] temp = new byte[length];
        System.arraycopy(array, start, temp, 0, length);
        output[i] = temp;
    }

    //
    return output;
}
```

I should note that I do not have a lot of experience with optimalisation or multithreading for that matter. my array chunks are 4096 bytes because the outputstream keeps giving me a indexoutofrangeexception if I go much higher than that.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is it right to blame your code? Have you calculated how much time it should take to transfer 67MB bytes with 115200 BAUD? Please tell.

Comment: `this.video` Do you have 67 MB in memory?

Comment: `byte[][] byteArrayChunks = createArrayChunk(this.video, 4096);` And now you have yet again placed 67 MB in memory!!? That does not look like a good approach. You can expect memory problems. You do not need this construct to begin with.`Any help is appreciated` That why i tell you.

Comment: out.write(this.video); Did you try that?

Comment: this.video is a byte array of 67MB (a .mp4 file) wihch as far as I know caanot be compressed that much. trying to write the file all at once causes a indexoutofbounds exception as the outputstream has its limits.

Comment: You have only reacted to my last comment. But who talked about compressing? Not me! Please start answering with my first comment.

Comment: Sending 115200 BAUD is about equal to 11520 bytes per second over a serial port. so an 67MB file takes about should take about 67.000.000 bytes / 11520 ~ 5816 second = 1 hour and 35 minutes. Wait if thats correct then it takes a long time anyway.

I do not know how to reply to specific commend as the option is not shown sorry.

Comment: It looks as if your code is not causing a delay indeed. Unless it takes three hours which you did not tell. I wonder what option you are looking for. But now that you reacted to my first comment you could also react to the second and third. No options needed. Why do you place such a big file twice completely in memory is the question.

Comment: Yesy this.video is 67MB in memory. I know it is bad but I am looking for other options